# Oracle- Inner join vs where condition

Tags: sql, oracle

[Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWkZB.jpg)

Database Link - https://github.com/lerocha/chinook-database

**problem** -Your task is to identify the playlists(Playlist id and name) that do not contain any
tracks for the artists "Black Sabbath" nor "Chico Buarque"

### **Possible queries**

1. 

```
select distinct Playlist.Playlistid ,Playlist.name
from Playlist
inner join 
PlaylistTrack on PlaylistTrack.Playlistid=Playlist.Playlistid
inner join
Track on Track.Trackid=PlaylistTrack.Trackid
inner join
Album on Album.Albumid=Track.Albumid
inner join
Artist on Artist.Artistid=Album.Artistid
where Artist.name not in('Black Sabbath','Chico Buarque');
```

2. 

```
SELECT playlistId, name FROM Playlist WHERE playlistId NOT IN 
(SELECT pt.playlistId FROM PlaylistTrack pt, Track t, Album b, Artist a 
WHERE pt.trackId = t.trackId AND t.albumId = b.albumId 
AND b.artistId =a.artistId AND 
(a.name = 'Black Sabbath' OR a.name = 'Chico Buarque') )
```

[Playlist containing tracks of 'Chico Buarque' OR 'Black Sabbath'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Pa6j.png)

[Output of Query 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXaft.png)

[Output of Query 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxxgT.png)

Playlist id 1,11,8,17 are the playlist that contains tracks of "Chico Buarque" or "Black Sabbath".

Therefore, they should not be displayed in the output of above two queries.
But these playlist id's are coming in the output of query 1.

And the output of query 2 doesn't include these playlists(This query yields the correct result).

Both queries look identical,but the outputs are different.
Can anyone tell what i am missing here?

Comment: `where not <something>` will return rows, for that `<something>` predicate is `false`. Playlist may contain many tracks, so restricting the track to be not equal to something just returns other tracks in the playlist

Comment: could you post the sample data for each of those tables that you were running your queries on?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more specific along with output of queries.

Comment: @astentx it is also returning the cases which i have put inside "not in" condition in the first query

Comment: @mangusta i have uploaded the picture of the schema of complete database

Comment: First of all, when you want to select from a table where something does exist or not exist, use `[NOT] EXISTS` or `[NOT] IN`. Don't join. The problem with your join is that you select all playlists that contain an artist who is not 'Black Sabbath' or 'Chico Buarque'. This should be true about almost all playlists, I guess. It suffices to contain one track by some other artist to make it into your result list.

Comment: Are you learning SQL right now? In your second query you are using a join syntax that was used in the 1980s. I do hope nobody is teaching you this. In case, quit the tutorial, class, book, whatever. Don't use comma-separated joins. Use explicite joins like in your first query.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes i'm learning sql. The first query was written by me but it is not yielding correct result so i just googled for the right query and got the second one.

Answer (score 0):

In your query you select all tracks that are not by Black Sabbath or Chico Buarque. From these you select the playlists. This means rather than asking "give me all playlists that don't contain a track of xyz" you are asking "give me all playlists that contain a track that is not of xyz". This is something entirely different.

Here are some queries that do the job:

### NOT EXISTS

```
select playlistid, name 
from playlist pl
where not exists
(
  select null
  from playlisttrack pt
  join track t on t.trackid = pt.trackid
  join album al on al.albumid = t.albumid
  where pt.playlistid = pl.playlistid
  and al.artistid in 
  (
    select artistid
    from artist
    where name in ('Black Sabbath', 'Chico Buarque')
  )
);
```

### NOT IN

```
select playlistid, name 
from playlist 
where playlistid not in 
(
  select pt.playlistid
  from playlisttrack pt
  join track t on t.trackid = pt.trackid
  join album al on al.albumid = t.albumid
  where al.artistid in 
  (
    select artistid
    from artist
    where name in ('Black Sabbath', 'Chico Buarque')
  )
);
```

### Conditional aggregation

```
select playlistid, name 
from playlist 
where playlistid in 
(
  select pt.playlistid
  from playlisttrack pt
  join track t on t.trackid = pt.trackid
  join album al on al.albumid = t.albumid
  join artist a on a.artistid = al.artistid
  group by pt.playlistid
  having count(case when a.name in ('Black Sabbath', 'Chico Buarque') then 1 end) = 0
);
```

Comment: Such a comment is not really helpful. You should always say *what* is not working. This can be rows that must not be in the results or rows that are missing from the results or an error for instance. In this case it seems you got an error that there is no `artistid` in the `playlisttrack` table. It would have saved me some work, had you just told me so. I looked at your data model, saw this and added the missing link (the tabkes `track` and `album`) to my queries. I suppose they run fine now.

Comment: "give me all playlists that don't contain a track of xyz"  and "give me all playlists that contain a track that is not of xyz". How these statements are different in terms of yielding the result.

Comment: Say a list contains two tracks, one by uvw, one by xyz. If looking for "playlists that don't contain tracks by xyz", you won't get this list, because it contains a track by xyz. If looking for "playlists that contain a track that is not of xyz", you will get this list, because it contains a track by uvw.

Comment: Understood! How can i avoid such pitfalls in future?

Comment: Haha, that's a good question. I don't think there is a pattern to avoid such things. But it becomes clear that it is important to describe the task *precisely*. It often helps to make up sample data and think of exceptions. In your case: playlists with songs of both artists, playlists with one or the other, playlists with none of them, maybe playlists consisting only of songs by them, etc. And then describe exactly by which rule(s) you want to select data. If you get this precise in human language, it will become easier to translate into SQL.

Comment: Keywords like **exist**, **at least**, **exactly**, **all**, **both**, **every**, **and**, **or**, **not** etc. can help formulating the rules in human language. Some of them have an equivalent in SQL, for the others find a way to express the same thing differently (i.e. with SQL words). Some tasks can be said in different ways. E.g. "select the last order per client", "Per client select the order with the newest date", "Per client select the order for which no later order exists", etc. Reformulating a rule can sometimes help to find an according SQL approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.PLAYLISTID,P.NAME FROM PLAYLIST AS P 
JOIN PLAYLISTTRACK AS PT ON PT.PLAYLISTID=P.PLAYLISTID
JOIN TRACK AS T ON T.TRACKID=PT.TRACKID
JOIN ALBUM AS A ON A.ALBUMID=T.ALBUMID
JOIN ARTIST AS AT ON AT.ARTISTID=A.ARTISTID
WHERE AT.NAME NOT IN ('BLACK SABBATH','CHICO BUARQUE') 
GROUP BY P.PLAYLISTID,P.NAME ORDER BY P.PLAYLISTID
```

Comment: Just a code can't be an answer, need more comment/detail about how this fix / respond the question

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i agree with @YLR.

Comment: @shrijoy chowdhury. Your output is same as my output of query 1 which is wrong. Also you will have to remove "as" to make your query work.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner explained it well in his answer and comments.

Comment: @VaibhavGautam "as" is optional and can be written or omitted. I never faced problem with this while writing the code in MySQL command line. Can you kindly provide the correct solution?

Comment: This question is for Oracle. My second query is correct, Also you can refer to @ThorstenKettner answer below and the comments following that.